# Foreground, background color of scroll position indicator

Tags: tmux

I was trying to change the foreground and background color of the scroll position indicator in tmux but didn't find the option name in the manuals. Was wondering if there is a setting to change that. See pic for what I mean by the scroll position indicator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The window option you're looking for is: `mode-style`. For example, you could put this in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g mode-style bg=brightred,fg=white,bold
```

Note that it also affect the window choser cursor (`choose-window`, `<prefix> w` by default)